# Incorrect page display with arrow notation in PHP

Tags: php, html, notation

I'm very new to coding in PHP and I've been trying some courses, but I can't seem to figure this out.
I wanted to display a page I had to create in a course, but it seemed like the code "broke up" after the first instance of the arrow notation. This is a simplified version of the page (but with the same error).

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title> Hello World! </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php
                class Dog{
                    public $numLegs = 4;
                    public $name;
                    public function __constructor($name){
                           $this->name = $name;
                    }
                    public function greet(){
                        return "Hello! My name is " . $this->name . "!";
                    }
                }

                $Doug = new Dog("Doug");

                echo $Doug->greet();

            ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the output in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: looks like your webserver doesn't know it should be interpreting this as a PHP file.  Are you using Apache?  What is the file name?

Comment: save this page like php. e.g. index.php not index.html

Comment: Change `__constructor` to `__construct` Also otherwise the sample works fine for me! Think your server don't support php OR you didn't saved the file with `*.php`

Comment: Are you actually running a web server, or just attempting to load a `.php` file by opening it in your browser? You will need a web server to invoke the PHP interpreter and send its output to the browser as html.

Comment: Oh wow I forgot about all those things, .php, the webserver... thank you! Guess I still have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code,

you have to change constructor to construct on line no 11

and save this file with .php extension

hope you will get the answer

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title> Hello World! </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php
                class Dog{
                    public $numLegs = 4;
                    public $name;
                    public function __construct($name){
                           $this->name = $name;
                    }
                    public function greet(){
                        return "Hello! My name is " . $this->name . "!";
                    }
                }

                $Doug = new Dog("Doug");

                echo $Doug->greet();

            ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you, the program that checked the code for me somehow accepted __constructor every single time..